# Search and connect to wifi in Client side

Tags: javascript, networking, client-side-scripting

How can i search for wifi active devices and connect to them in client side and share messages. I want to create a website which will search for wifi devices and connect to them and send and receive data(provide if the user devices like mobiles and computer are having a router). Which framework should i use or any other method without using a framework.

**Edit 1**
I'm practising on localhost and want to scan for wifi active connections on client side and connect to one of them to share data. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: If your website isn't on a working connection in the first place, how is anybody going to visit it?  When your PHP website gets a request, you can safely assume that there's a connection and respond to that request.

Comment: You cant do this from PHP. 
PHP is server side code and never runs on the client.

Comment: I think the OP is running php on a local server and trying to fund devices on the local wifi.. As ArcSet said, it's impossible from php

Comment: @ArcSet Actually, I once configured IE5.5 to run PHP as a client side interpreter. It was nasty business which deserved to be nuked from orbit. Here's a remnant of someone else doing it: https://www.sitepoint.com/client-side-php-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: All right , @ArcSet said it can't be done using php (server side) .. Ok I agree (fault of my poor knowledge ) ;  but can it be done using client side ? If yes  then what i should use ?

Comment: You could use java.

Comment: Thanks, can you please say a specific part of java or any links , references

Comment: @ArcSet can it be done using Jquery ?

Comment: jquery is library for javascript.. As of now no javascript cant do that. Javascript relies on how the browser wants to interpret it and manage it.

JAVA applet. would be where you start. there is lots of documentation online. The most popular IDE for it is Eclipse I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised to see this question under the PHP and Wordpress tags. Wifi is obviously client side. More, it is on the client's hardware side. Only technologies directly handling the customers' computer hardware can handle this.

Comment: "Wifi is obviously client side."  Okay
regarding 'Wordpress tag' : I meant if there are any plugins in wordpress (as i m building a wordpress site) which will help me to complete the task..